# Background not adjusting on mobile view

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design, background-image

My background does not resize along with my window. It adjusts when the window gets bigger, not when I adjust it smaller.

background-size: cover does not help with the resizing

**Full Screen Normal Size:**

[image: 1]

**Mobile Size**

[image: 2]

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <?php require_once('header-only.php');
       require_once('header-addon.php'); ?>

 <div class="bg-newest">
   <br><div class="container pt-5"><br>
   <br><h2 class="bold-font color-black p-left-15 pt-5">Newest</h2>
   <br><br><br>
       </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg-newest {
  background-image: url('MY-IMAGE-LINK');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: try to add background-size:100%

Comment: The background image seem to have covered the height 100% though. How would you expect the image to look in the mobile version when header changes ratio?

Comment: expecting the image to fit in the mobile view (same look)

Comment: It won't look the same when you have `cover` and the container has a different ratio than the background image. You would need to use `contain` instead of `cover`. However, then it won't take up both 100% width and height of the box unless the box is of the same ratio as the image.

Comment: Use media query for mobile view and set `background size` to `100%` and you can also set it to `contain` if it suits your screen.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your background element is stretching past the screen, kind of like this. [image]

To fix this, I would recommend setting the background element's width to 100%.

(Sorry the image is so large, I don't know how to scale it)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting width of '.bg-newest' element to 100% and background-size property to 'contain' . Also you need to reduce the padding-top value of
`<h2 class="bold-font color-black p-left-15 pt-5">Newest</h2>`

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <?php require_once('header-only.php');
    require_once('header-addon.php'); ?>

 <div class="bg-newest">
  <br><div class="container pt-5"><br>
  <br><h2 class="bold-font color-black p-left-15">Newest</h2>
   <br><br><br>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

**CSS**

```
 .bg-newest {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('MY-IMAGE-LINK');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.bg-newest h2{
   padding:top: 5em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
 .bg-newest h2{
   padding:top: 2em; /* Reduce padding top */
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting the background image size to 100%

```
  .bg-newest {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
```